# What is mapbox-gl-csp-worker.js in Webpack bundle analyzer?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, mapbox, bundle, webpack-bundle-analyzer

Like many before me, I've gotten to the point in my project that I am trying to slim down my bundle size.

What I don't understand is that I have two different kinds of Mapbox. When analyzing my bundle with Webpack bundle analyzer:

Mapbox 1:

[image]

Mapbox 2:

[image]

I don't understand the purpose of the second Mapbox. What is mapbox-gl-csp-worker.js and how does that differ from mapbox-gl.js?